# How to render different classes on span using React.js?

Tags: reactjs

```
<span className="inactiveBtn">Inactive</span>
    <span className="activeBtn">Active</span>
    <span className="deletedBtn">To be Delted</span>
```

I am using these 3 spans in my table column, but I want to render it dynamically, as in if text is active, inactive or deleted then it should render its respective class and text to the span.

Comment: Use https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

Answer (score 3):

you can store the three options in an array:

```
const options = [{label: 'Inactive', class: 'inactiveBtn'},
{label: 'Active', class: 'activeBtn'},
{label: 'To Be Deleted', class: 'deletedBtn'}];

{options.map((item, index) => 
 <span key={index} className={item.class}>{item.label}</span> )}
```

Comment: can you please create a demo file

Comment: https://codepen.io/nomanhassan/pen/GPQamq

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator to determine what class to use.

It's like a shortened if else statement.

```
condition is true ? useTrueClass : otherwiseUseThisClass
```

Assuming you have a variable in place for each button that keeps track of the status of said button. Use, that variable to set the condition.

```
<span className={isActive ? activeBtnClass: inactiveBtnClass}>Active</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many dynamic classes you need to add as your project grows it's probably worth checking out the [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) utility by JedWatson on GitHub. It allows you to represent your conditional classes as an object and returns those that evaluate to true.

So as an example from its React documentation:

```
import classnames from "classnames";

/**
 * *
 */

let btnClass = classnames({
    'inactiveBtn': this.state.text === 'Inactive',
    'activeBtn': this.state.text === 'Active',
    'deletedBtn': this.state.text === 'To be Delted'
});

<span className={btnClass}>this.state.text</span>;
```

Since React triggers a re-render when there is a state change, your dynamic class names are handled naturally and kept up to date with the state of your component.

Hope this will help you!